# Where can I find an interactive graphic showing the development of countries?

Tags: development

I remember once finding a graphic which let you slide back and forth, showing how third world countries had developed over time. It would be really handy to find it again, but I've tried all the keywords I can think of and it's not coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is the original that you had in mind, but [Gapminder](http://www.gapminder.org/) allows you to interactively explore a variety of data sets relating to both developed and developing countries.

[image]

Comment: This is not the same site, but has the same data I think. Thanks!